# Using nHibernate is it possible to mix a QueryOver result with a linq query?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a QueryOver result set

```
var res = GetResults(session, group_id, search_criteria).Select(x => x.GroupId);
```

I know the following gives an error.
My question is whether there some way to use res in my linq query?

```
var linqResults = (from vg in session.Query<vGraph>()
  join rs in res on vg.vId equals res.GroupId
  select vg);
```

Comment: i dont think it's possible, because QueryOver and Linq use different implementations under the hood (QueryOver -> Criteria, Linq -> HQL)

Comment: I think you may be right.  Any way to convert the QO into a form that LINQ can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still resort to a linq query which uses the executed results of you first query to.

```
var res = GetResults(session, group_id, search_criteria).Select(x => x.GroupId).List();

var linqResults =
    (from vg in session.Query<vGraph>()
     where vg.vId.IsIn(res)
     select vg);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.  This of course assumes that res has less than 2100 items.  But ok for my purposes